# Converting a Spark dataframe to Term document matrix in R using sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, tm, sparklyr, term-document-matrix

I have a code in R which needs to be scaled to use big data. I am using Spark for this and the package that seemed most convenient was sparklyr. However, I am unable to create a TermDocument matrix from a Spark dataframe. Any help would be great.

input_key is the dataframe having the following schema.

```
ID  Keywords
 1   A,B,C
 2   D,L,K
 3   P,O,L
```

My code in R was the following.

```r
mycorpus <- input_key

corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(mycorpus$Keywords))

path_matrix <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
```

Answer (score 1):

Such direct attempt won't work. Sparklyr tables are just views of underlying JVM objects and are not compatible with generic R packages.

While some capability to invoke arbitrary R code through `sparklyr::spark_apply`, the input and the output have to be data frame, and it is unlikely to translate to your particular use case.

If you committed to using Spark / `sparklyr` you should rather consider rewriting your pipeline using built-in ML transformers, as well as 3rd party Spark packages like [Spark CoreNLP interface](https://github.com/databricks/spark-corenlp) or [John Snow Labs Spark NLP](https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/components.html).